# positional projection cannot be used with a literal error in mongo 4.4

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a query that was working with older version:

```
await this.model.findOne({ userEmail, 'environments.envId': envId },{ 'environments.$': envId })
```

But I get error here at `environments.$`. I am not finding anything related to this error on web.

Answer (score 1):

With $ projections You can only use a number. The following code will work:

```
await this.model
    .findOne({
         userEmail, 
         'environments.envId': envId 
    },
    { 
         'environments.$': 1 
    })
```

more info here:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/